# FPDF with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf

I am attempting to use the FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/) PHP addon for my website that uses Laravel. I want to be able to dynamically create a PDF.

I have stored the libraries' files in the folder: '/public/vendor'.
This is what I have so far:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/fpdf/fpdf.php';
```

which works fine. However when I try to use the FPDF class using:

```
  $pdf = new FPDF('P', 'pt', array(500,233));
```

I get the error: Class "'App\Console\Commands\FPDF' not found"

How can I fix this to use the library. I do not have access to command line so I have to manually import any folders or files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update:: I do not have any access to the console so i cannot use composer. Any way to still do this?

Comment: First, you should not "require" any file directly, composer will do it for you. You should also not modify anything in vendor folder or even upload it to the server. and lastly, the namespace is incorrect, you need to add `use Fpdf/Fpdf;` at he start of the file or do `new \Fpdf\Fpdf('P', 'pt', array(500,233));`. another solution is to declare an alias for the `"FPDF" => \Fpdf\Fpdf::class` in config/app.php to be able to use `FPDF` directly

Comment: Using an autoloader, you would `use FPDF\FPDF;` at the top of the file, which allows you to use the class name (`new FPDF(...);`). Without an autoloader, you need to `require_once` (note using `_once`), and then use the full path with beginning slash, `new \FPDF\FPDF(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally if using Laravel, you should load it via composer the get it to work correctly.

If you do not have access to composer on the server, you could download the project, make sure you are running the same version of PHP as the server and run `composer install fpdf/fpdf`. Re-upload the composer.json, composer.lock and vendor folder.

https://packagist.org/packages/fpdf/fpdf

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
 $pdf = new \Fpdf\Fpdf('P', 'pt', array(500,233));
```

FPDF is in the root namespace and you are within another namespace.

Comment: I am still getting an error using this: "Class 'Fpdf\Fpdf' not found"

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend using https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf which can be installed via composer

It supports blade views and you can pass variables to it just like in view()

Comment: How can I do this without using composer as I do not have access to command line